# Change button colour

Tags: javascript, css, button

My idea is to show an image on a map as soon as I press a button. I would like to change the colour of the button after it has been clicked and it should stay that colour until I deselect the button. The colour of the button should then change back to its original colour.

Here is the code for the button:

```
<button type="button" class="Button" id="tram7" class="deselected"> Tramlinie 7 </button>
```

And here is the function that inserts an image to the map:

```
$('#tram7')[0].onclick = function() {
    if (overlayTram7.getMap() == map) {
        $('#tram7').addClass('deselected');
        overlayTram7.setMap(null);
    } else {
        $('#tram7').removeClass('deselected'); 
        overlayTram7.setMap(map);
    }
};
```

The style change worked with a hover, but I don't know how to change the style of a clicked button.

```
.Button {
 font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
 font-size:13px;
 font-weight: bold; 
 width: 160px;
 height: 25px;
 background:grey;
 color: white
}

.Button:hover {
 color: white;
 background:green
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "$('#tram7')[0]." why? try $('#tram7').on('click',function(){//your code here}); 
Also can you provide a jsfiddle.net demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't too clear for me. Are you wanting to change the color ONLY while the user is clicking on the button? If so, that's pretty easy, just with CSS:

You'll want the [psuedo-selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp), `:active`

```
.Button:active {
   color: white;
   background:green
}
```

[**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/9dZy2/1/)

---

Update: You clarified that you want the button's color to be changed after being clicked. Essentially acting like a toggle. Luckily JQuery has a simple solution for you: [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

[Updated example using **`toggleClass()`**](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/9dZy2/4/)

Comment: No, I want the colour to stay changed after the click. It should stay the other colour until I click the button again.

Comment: See my updated example that allows the button's class to be toggled.

Comment: If I look at the demo, it seems like this is what I'm looking for. However, I don't completely understand how to change my code now. Do I delete the "addClas"s and "removeClass" functions or should I just add the toggleClass?

Comment: You should be able to delete `addClass()` and `removeClass()`. `toggleClass()` is meant to be a replacement for those. You could still use `add/removeClass()`, but it's just extra lines of code that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The `:active` pseudo-selector should be what you're looking for

```
.Button:active {
 color: white;
 background:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this isn't what I was looking for. With the active function the colour only changes while I'm clicking the button. But I would like the button to stay in the new colour until I click the button again.

Answer (score 0):

Use toggleClass in your click callback to add/remove a class which will style your button:

```
$('#tram7').toggleClass('clicked');
```

And the class:

```
.Button.clicked {
 color: white;
 background:blue
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5m9h6/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this isn't what I was looking for. With the active function the colour only changes while I'm clicking the button. But I would like the button to stay in the new colour until I click the button again